# Java App engine backend shuts down abruptly, how to resume work?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, backend

I have Cron job which runs every 30mins and queues a task to be executed on a Dynamic Backend (B2).
The Backend loops and does some work, then sleeps for few minutes and then repeats the work till finally the complete job is over after few hours, after which the Backend shuts down. (Till the backend is running, no new Task is actioned)

Now two days in a row, I have seen my Backend stop abruptly (after 1.5hrs) with the familiar "Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.". I have searched through the forums but could not identify WHY exactly my backend shuts down (apart from the theoretical list of reasons that Appengine doc provides). I have checked my DS/Memcache operations, Memory and all looks normal. I upgraded my backend from B1 to B2, but no luck.

Q1. Does anybody know how to debug this issue further?

Q2. Even after this I wish that the job should be completed. If I register a shutdown hook LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook(), what is a good way to ensure that the job is resumed (considering that the Cron job could be still  29minutes away from next execution, and I want the job to do its stuff every 2 minutes)

Comment: What did mean by have it sleep?

Comment: Hi Siva, my backend logic involves an infinite while loop (till it breaks after some condition is satisifed). Sleep = Thread.sleep for 2 mins. I used a Backend so that I can rely on the state of previous computation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the same has happened to me. I have a backend that uses constant memory and cpu. Apengine shuts it down periodically, usually after 15min but sometimes before that. The docs say that it may get shut down without explanation, it will notify the backend and then shut it down.
You are supposed to handle it gracefully which means it can work by chunks and restart its work. If you. Ant divide the work in chunks dont use backends, use a compute engine instance.

Comment: In my case I need to use gcm and endpoints to interface with the mobile. Don't think Compute engine will help?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you'd have to take a closer look at the logs, app engine does [promise](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/#Java_Shutdown) to indicate shutdown behaviour through a request to /_ah/stop so that would give more insights at the issue.

Now for your second question, stick with app engine's suggestions of having more than one instance. In your case you could move away from looping through some entity infinitely and going to sleep state. Instead have a cron which looks up a task queue and process a single task. If that's processed successfully mark it so somewhere or do so by removing it from the queue after you're done processing it. So in case of failures that task would still be available to be processed unless its marked successful and your additional instances can take over.

Comment: Sad and strange, that "backend" which was probably designed for long running operations is not dependable after all.

Comment: From production environments I've noticed this I guess this eventually happens and you just have to be sure your code and infrastructure can handle it

Comment: Surprisingly yesterday I had a first full run of the Backend with no stoppage. The only difference from prior runs is that this run was from 2:30pm IST - 7pm IST, whereas the earlier ones were from 7:30pm IST - 10:30pm IST. Wonder if the stability suffers during US business hours due to overload or something?

Comment: I don't think that would be a cause, but can't pin point till we can look at your code or the flow and use of services :)